# Swagger API Specification filenames

Tags: json, api, rest, api-design, swagger

I'm trying to use Swagger to create API documentation for an API we're building and I've never used it before.

The documentation on Github says that the Resources Listing needs t be at **/api-docs** and the various resource files need to be at **/api-docs/books** etc.

This makes naming files and folders very tricky. I think they expect the files to have no file names, rather than having a folder called /api-docs it has to be an extension-less file, then you can't put the resources in an api-docs folder because you can't call the folder that, so they suggest using a folder called /listings.

This folder doesn't appear in the URL structure of your documentation though, it's kind of invisible because you set the baseURL in your resources to the proper path, but it looks like that has to be an absolute path, which is awkward if you want to have it on several servers (local and production).

Maybe I just don't get it but this all seems to be absolutely nuts.

So, I have 2 questions.....

1) Can I give my resource listing file and my resource files a .json extension? This would make sense as it's a JSON file.

2) Can I use a relative path to the resource listing file in the baseURL in my resource files?

Ideally, my file structure would be flatter, like this...

```
/api-docs
    resources.json
    books.json
    films.json
```

Is Swagger flexible enough to do this?

It's an IIS server if that makes any difference (if the solution requires routing for example).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to put model files into a folder under the web root and could reference them like this.

```
 $ref: '/models/model.yml#/MyObject'
```

Relative paths also worked without a leading slash.

```
   $ref: 'models/model.yml#/MyObject'
```

Inside the model.yml, I can reference other objects int eh same file like this

```
 $ref: '#/MyObject2'.
```

However, I could only get the main swagger file to import model files. I could not get one model file to cross-reference another model file.

I was using a Tomcat web server but the principle will be the same.